# How to open and read the preview files in the network tab of dev tools

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to read the preview in the network tab of chrome dev tools using c# and selenium. I know c# but do not have any knowledge of selenium and do not know where to start.

I have looked at a lot of posts on this site referencing selenium and chrome dev tools but am none the wiser. I have added selenium.webdriver and selenium.werbdriver.chromedriver to my console app. I can navigate to a webpage and that is as far as I have got.

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
var cd = new ChromeDriver();
cd.Navigate().GoToUrl("whateverSiteYouWant");
```

This works fine but I don't know where to find more details on accessing the network tab programmatically, so any help pointing me in the right direction would be great.